# Set up Vue app run using Nginx on port 80 from Raspbian along with Flask backend running on port 8080

Tags: nginx, vue.js, raspbian

I have Nginx setup Flask based backend running on port 8080 with the below configuration

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name _;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/html/static/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @wsgi;
    }

    location @wsgi {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }

    location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }
}
```

I have also setup a systemd service that uses gunicorn to run the flask app using: `gunicorn --bind=unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock --workers=4 start_backend:web_app`

Now the above is working for Python Flask backend on port 8080, I also want to add Vue app on default port 80 as well.

### Update

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/dist;
        server_name _;

        location /static {
        alias  /var/www/html/dist/static/;
        }

        location / {
        root /var/www/html/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
                root /var/www/html;
                try_files $uri @wsgi;
        }

        location @wsgi {
            proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
            include proxy_params;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add another server block to serve the frontend.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
         root /path/to/dist;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I've based this code on [this tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/single-page-apps-with-vue-js-and-flask-deployment/) where `/path/to/dist` in the above example should be changed to `the dist directory of the Vue.js front-end from your vue app`.

If you have a read of the section **Setting Up Nginx** in this tutorial, you'll notice that they are serving the Flask application and the Vue.js fronted at different URLs in the same server block:

```
server {  
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.45.67.89;

    location /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/survey/flask-vuejs-survey/backend/surveyapi.sock;
    }

  location / {
    root /home/survey/flask-vuejs-survey/frontend/survey-spa/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

If this app will be facing the internet then this is probably a better way to do things, as port 8080 outgoing may be blocked by your users' internet provider.  With the second configuration everything is served through port 80.

You may have to adjust your `vue.js` app slightly to make it look for the API at `/api` (or something) leaving `/` free to serve the frontend.

Comment: Of course, in the wild if this isn't sitting behind another reverse proxy which implements SSL on port 443, and you're configuring the front-facing nginx server yourself, you should definately be using the [Mozilla nginx conf generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) as a starting point, and read the [Security/Server Side TLS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) guidance.

Comment: the answer almost seems to be in my question , where I am serving `/static` can be `/dist` for root

Comment: Now vuejs app loads up but the css/js folder under `/var/www/html/dist/static` are not visible.  And flask app I am serving from `/var/www/html/` on `/api` is not loading in browser. I have added an **update** above